# Can pineapple crown grow root in 24 hours?

Tags: roots, fruits, pineapple

I planted a crown of pineapple almost 24 hours ago, today it has been sitting on the windowsill. I am not sure if the roots have already grown up or what is that. I am very interested in growing fruits and vegetables. Any good resource for new beginners?

[image: roots of pineapple]
[image]

Comment: Have you considered that you may be looking at fibers from the leaves?

Comment: @Stephie nope. I m very new to this but it got me excited

Comment: No I wish it could

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not roots. Just loosened fibers from a leaf (top picture) and from the pulp (bottom picture). If you do things right and conditions are optimal then expect it to root within a couple of month. Visible roots will appear within a couple of weeks.

It is easy to find guides like [this one](https://www.southernliving.com/garden/edible/how-to-grow-pineapple-top).

It is my experience that you should try to remove as much as possible of pulp/fruit and partly dead leaves to avoid rot.

Comment: I saw this morning, as I have bad eyesight in the night. I am afraid if I tamper with it , it will just die?

Comment: Take a look at 0:21 in the video at the top of the linked page. This is how your crown should look like. Your photos show far too much useless material at the bottom including smaller leaves. Observe that the guide says "The **root buds** around the edge of the stem should be visible. ". Do not be afraid of letting it dry for days before you return it to a glass of water. (No direct sunlight)  Sometimes the crown is too old when you buy the pineapple: The core leaves are missing or too many leaves are brown or damaged.